# How to remove the focused row when a gridview is initially loaded

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, focus, devexpress

I have a DevExpress gridview that loads on my screen.  Initially, I do not want it to have a focus on any row.  Only after a user selects a row do I want there to be focus.  Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

if you have multiple rows selection option enabled on your grid you can call the

```
 gridView1.ClearSelection();
```

method on the gridview. However if it is not enables you have to call

```
gridView1.UnselectRow(5);
```

method. You can read all such methods [here](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_UnselectRowtopic)

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  Is there a way to identify when the grid initially loads?  Right now I have the following code in the FocusedRowChanged method:

     DataRow row = gridView.GetFocusedDataRow();
            if (row == null)
                clearControlValues();

I put the ClearSelection immediately after my InitializeComponent method, but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: why handle the FocusedRowChanged, you can call your method after assigning it to datasource

Comment: I initially tried to call the ClearSelection method immediately after assigning the datasource to the gridview, but the focus on the first row remained.

Comment: do you have multi selection enabled on your gridview?

Comment: I just realized that I don't.  I tried the same thing with the UnselectRow(0) statement, but with no luck.  Let me look around my code some more to see if anything funny is going on and I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

with Mvvm pattern you can try this.
I had the same problem and have solved it by overriding the OnPropertyChanged event of the GridView

```
protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) { base.OnPropertyChanged(e); this.ClearSelection(); }
```